# Where do I go in Windows Server 2012 to observe the replication of my domain information?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I am looking for and have not found where the user interface of Windows Server 2012's AD and Server Management tools, I can see the replication status of domain (Active Directory) data replication, similar to the stuff that you could query using `dfsrdiag` from the command line.

Is there something built in? I have found an installable tool `ADREPLSTATUS` that may offer some of this information, but I am wondering if there is any built in UI for this.

I have searched the Active Directory Administrative Center and the Server Manager to no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The old Replmon went out of style a long time ago.  See the AskDS post "Getting over Replmon":

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/07/01/getting-over-replmon.aspx

The idea is that repadmin, a command-line tool, can do everything and more that the GUI Replmon could do, only faster and more efficiently.

Then, if you still just really can't stand not having a GUI, then you can install AD Replication Status Tool, which you have already found.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005

Here's the AskDS post about that tool when it released just about a year ago:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/23/ad-replication-status-tool-is-live.aspx

> Ned here again. The AD Replication Monitor utility (Replmon.exe) was
>   introduced with the Windows Server 2000 Support Tools many years ago
>   as a GUI mechanism for performing certain DC admin tasks. With the
>   release of Window Server 2008 Replmon was not included and we stopped
>   making add-on Support Tools. Every few weeks someone asks me ‘where do
>   I download the Windows Server 2008 version of Replmon? Nowhere. It’s
>   done. Buried. Gone. Kaput. If you want it, you must run the old
>   Windows Server 2003 version. Today I will talk about moving on with
>   its supported replacement, Repadmin.exe.

Edit: Just to clarify, the standard suite of Remote Server Administration Tools such ADUC, Sites and Services, ADSI Edit, etc., are of course still included with Server 2012. You'll get them automatically on a DC, or on any member server if you install the RSAT optional feature. But for monitoring replication status, it's the repadmin command line tool, or the downloadable AD Replication Status tool.

Comment: I'm glad they made a new AD Repl Status UI tool!

Comment: I downloaded it and played with it a little, but honestly, I didn't find any use for it beyond what repadmin already does. But to each his own! :)

Comment: If the stock UI included EVEN an indication of the last and next sync time, and the last and next sync result, I'd be happy. As is, the UI ignores the existence of replication.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because for the vast majority of cases, AD replication is never an issue. However, you still have all the tools you need to troubleshoot it and monitor it. You have repadmin, and you have a free downloadable tool in AD Replication Status Monitor, and you have SCOM management packs if you really want to get in to it...